# unable to add builder.io to my existing app

Tags: vuejs3, builder.io

I am trying to add builder.io to my vue 3 app. When reading the [documentation](https://www.builder.io/c/blueprints/announcement-bar), I am doing it correctly when trying to add a `announcement-bar`.

In my package.json file I have the dependency needed

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@animxyz/vue3": "^0.6.7",
    "@builder.io/vue": "^0.1.12",
```

main.ts

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import './index.css';
import App from './App.vue';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import router from './router/route';
import BuilderVue from "builder.io/vue";
import '@builder.io/sdk-vue/vue3/css';

const API_KEY = process.env.BUILDER_API_KEY;
const ENV = process.env.BUILDER_ENV || "production";
const builder = BuilderVue({
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    env: ENV,
    data: {
        space: "test_poc",
    },
});

createApp(App)
    .use(router)
    .use(createPinia())
    .use(builder)
    }).mount('#app')
```

[image]

In my header I added the sdk library

```
import { RenderContent } from '@builder.io/sdk-vue/vue3';
```

....

[image]

```
<template>
         <RenderContent
          model="announcement-bar"
          :content="content"
      />
</template>
```

However it cannot find it import.

I have deleted the `node_modules` and cleaned my cache. Still it is unable to find it.
I am not sure if this is related to vue 3 or if the docs are out of date.

Has anyone else had similar issues?

Comment: In your first screenshot, you're missing the `@`.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks. But even with the `@` I get `Vue: Could not find a declaration file for module  @builder.io/vue`

Comment: Where'd you get this starter code? That package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@builder.io/vue) appears to not have been updated in two years. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@builder.io/sdk-vue appears to be the more recent version. I'd start with an official Builder.io start guide or starter repo. https://www.builder.io/m/vue has starter code about 3/4 of the way down the page.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you happen to fix it?